# How to use different color in Angular Echarts xAxis Label by condition?

Tags: angular, echarts

HTML

```
<p>Stack Chart</p>
<stack-chart></stack-chart>
<p></p>
<div *ngFor="let date of dates">{{ date }}</div>
```

APP TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  dates = [ 'Wednesday', 'Friday'];
}
```

STACK TS

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as echarts from "echarts";
// var echarts = require('echarts')

import $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'stack-chart',
  template: `<div class="mGraph-wrapper">
  <div class="mGraph" id="mGraph_sale"></div>
</div>`,
  styles: [`
  .mGraph-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 239px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .mGraph-wrapper .mGraph{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }`]
})
export class StackchartComponent implements OnInit {

  dates: string[] = [];
  // data Structure for Series
   data=[{
    legend:"Marketing",
    dataPoints:[220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
  },{
    legend:"Sales",
    dataPoints:[150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
  },{
    legend:"HumanResource",
    dataPoints:[170, 132, 291, 254, 145, 390, 610]
  }];
  // @Input() name: string;
  // @Input() data:any;
  series=[];
  legends=[];
  constructor(private elm:ElementRef){
    this.dates = [ 'Wednesday', 'Friday'];
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    let stackchart = echarts.init($(this.elm.nativeElement).find('#mGraph_sale')[0]);
    this.data.forEach(x=>{
      this.series.push({
        name:x.legend,
        type:'line',
        stack:'Total Amount',
        areaStyle:{normal:{}},
        data:x.dataPoints
        })

        this.legends.push(x.legend)
      
    })

    stackchart.setOption({
      tooltip:{
        trigger:'axis',
        axisPointer:{
          type:'cross',
          label:{backgroundColor:'#6a7985'}
        }
      },
    //    title: {
    //     left: 'center',
    //     text: 'Stack Chart',
    // },
       legend:{data:this.legends},
        grid: {
        left: '10%',
        right: '10%',
        bottom: '5%',
        containLabel: true
      },
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          boundaryGap: false,
          data: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
        }
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          type: 'value'
        }
      ],
      series: this.series,
    },
   
    )

  }
}
```

I want to Change the Echarts xAxis Label color by Some condition, If the condition is true only some of the xAxis label color change, other xAxis label should be like the previous one.

Here I want to change the Wednesday and Friday color to some color and other dates should be in same color by some condition.

here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/echarts-demo-angular-dxavkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackchart.component.ts%3AL47

Answer (score 0):

Use a function for `xAxis.axisLabel.color` and put your conditions inside.

```js
xAxis: {
  axisLabel: {
    color: function (value, index) {
      return (value == "Wednesday" || value == "Friday") ? 'green' : 'red';
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: @A mere dev I need to check that conditionally, comparing two arrays if both arrays have wednesday and friday then i need to change the color for this particular date.

Comment: I believe you can do this inside the function (changing the conditions I put to yours)

Comment: How to do that ? seriously I don't know what to do when it's coming to put that condition inside this function ?